# Как сделать отступы в HTML?

Tags: html, css, отступы

Вот пример моего кода:

```
<p>Первая строка</p>
<p>Вторая строка</p>
```

Я бы хотел добавить так называемую красную строку, или отступ, но только в первом параграфе.
Раньше я использовал четыре `&nbsp;`, но хочу поменять метод.

### Обновление

Я использую

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Только в первом параграфе это странно, по общепринятой практике типографики отступ добавляется для всех абзацев

Comment: Я в 1 параграф пишу весь абзац, как бы тупо это не было.

Comment: Но всё же `p:first-child {text-indent: 2em;}` или `p:first-of-type` например

Comment: Работает! Пиши в ответы, приму

Comment: @andreymal Читай сверху

Answer (score 1):

Правильно будет выделить классом

```
<p class="start">Первая строка</p>
<p>Вторая строка</p>
```

А в стилях определить так:

```
.start {
  text-indent: 2%;
}
```

Есть и другие варианты. Они описаны в статье
https://domhtml.ru/abzacznyj-otstup-html/